# .htaccess variable backreferencing

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

On my site I use a download portal to count downloads of all the files.
I want the user to be redirected to the download page if they try to download a file. (this works now)

The download portal has a download button that simply posts to the same page with no parameters but as a side effect, causes the referer and request uri to be the same. (I want to use this)

Problem: the rewrite rule is not working.

Example:

On hxxp://somesite.com/index.php I click a link to download hxxp://somesite.com/pub/somefile.pdf

- the request_uri is /pub/somefile.pdf but it shows the download.php portal
  because the http_referer is hxxp://somesite.com
- user clicks download, and the page reloads
  the request uri is /pub/somefile.pdf
  the http referer is hxxp://somesite.com/pub/somefile.pdf
  the download commences because the end of the http_referer equals request_uri

The .htaccess file is hxxp://somesite.com/pub/.htaccess

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI}:%{HTTP_REFERER} !(.*):\1$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^.*$ /download.php [L]
```

The download portal just keeps appearing and won't let the file though.

Please help.